# UART Issues with MCP39F511

Tags: pcb-design, uart, c++, crosstalk

I've been trying to debug a UART communication issue on a custom design based on [ADM00667](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/adm00667#utm_medium=Press-Release&utm_term=MCP39F511_PR_4-21-15&utm_content=AIPD&utm_campaign=Board) development board where there are only a few minor changes.

I have the dev kit hooked up to an nRF52840 BLT MCU and the code works flawlessly, I'm able to send and set registers, and have been reliably getting data from the setup for three + weeks now.

I've connected TX/RX 3.3V and GND between the nRF52840 and MCP39F511 Dev Kit. Based on this setup I've spun a PCBA for a product. When I load the code and check COM with a logic get a strange event on the UART bus. The baud rate is set at 9600, so slow, and the logic level is 3.3V.

During normal operation I send a read command and wait a few ms for the data and read it. Working it looks like this.

[image]

What I'm gettin on the custom PCB is the correct data being sent but before the TX has completed RX responds with data that makes no sense and has no relevance in the MCP39F511A datasheet.

[image]

I've tried a factory reset of the chip based on the datasheet and get no ACK or NAK back. At first I thought it was crosstalk but after looking at the scope capture data found the RX line to be too strong of signal operating between 3.3V, and that the data was repeatable, everytime I try to communicate with the MCP on our custom PCB I get similar data.

[image]

The only differences are trace lengths, and the isolation chips. The ADM00667 board uses ACSL-7210-50RE even though the reference schematic uses the FOD8012AR2 that I used on our PCBA.

I've checked for shorts on all the pins on all UX chips, and found nothing. I've cleaned all flux from the board, added wires from all pins to bypass the traces from UART to make sure it wasn't crosstalk and still get the same exact scope capture.

I'm unclear if the MCP39F511A needs to be set up before data can be read, but the datasheet says the chip comes pre calibrated. "Fast Calibration Routines And Simplified Command Protocol" So I've tried changing the calibration parameters and I still get this RX noise/error.

I'm relatively new to debugging UART, and wanted to know if this is a problem someone might have encountered before and if I'm misinterpreting my observation wrong. I'm out of ideas as I have a DEV setup that works and two PCBA we’ve created that have the same exact issues. I'm happy it's repeatable because it makes debugging easier. I'm still trying to set other registrars and or clear system errors so I'll update once I've done that. But I'm not sure what else to try if those two parents also fail.

I'm open to paying for help, so if you have the time and want to make some cash and dive into this issue deeper I'm happy to work out a deal to get resolution and hopefully learn something.

Comment: Post the schematics, and check if the ground is connected, not just TX and RX.

Comment: It is common for default 9600 then you set the baud rate you want

Comment: Link to Schematic https://drive.google.com/file/d/16oI44IZtSE8eac1qqFPlBlI0wal3mxt8/view?usp=sharing. The GND is connected and I've checked continuity between the MCP39f511 pads to AGND and GNDB. There is an isolated DC/DC that separates the MCU and the MCP39F511, which is new to the design but should have an impact on performance. Well Unless 3.4V is too high for the chip...